# Why can't dropwizard configure my logger?

Tags: java, logging, jetty, dropwizard

I am simply trying to add logging configuration to dropwizard's yaml config file.  I'm running dropwizard version 0.9.2, and my yaml contains this:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: ./log/mylogfile.log
      threshold: ALL
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./log/mylogfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
      logFormat: # TODO
```

and my fatjar definitely has

META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory

which contains

```
io.dropwizard.logging.ConsoleAppenderFactory
io.dropwizard.logging.FileAppenderFactory
io.dropwizard.logging.SyslogAppenderFactory
```

but I am getting this on startup...

```
9:29:28 AM web.1 |    * Failed to parse configuration at: logging.appenders.[0]; Could not resolve type id 'file' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory]: known type ids = [AppenderFactory]
9:29:28 AM web.1 |   at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.salesforce.analytics.query.AppConfiguration["logging"]->io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory["appenders"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

any help as to what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: This only happens when running through your fat-jar? Is your classpath configured correctly?

Comment: yah it's a fatjar, something else needed on classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using tab in your yml file instead use double space i'm using following log configurations and its working fine, also verify you pom file you need to include maven shade plugin also added my pom file's build part

```
logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    "org.skife.jdbi.v2": TRACE
  appenders:
    - type: file
      # The file to which current statements will be logged.
      currentLogFilename: ./logs/mylogfile.log

      # When the log file rotates, the archived log will be renamed to this and gzipped. The
      # %d is replaced with the previous day (yyyy-MM-dd). Custom rolling windows can be created
      # by passing a SimpleDateFormat-compatible format as an argument: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}".
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/mylogfile-%d.log.gz

      # The number of archived files to keep.
      archivedFileCount: 5

      # The timezone used to format dates. HINT: USE THE DEFAULT, UTC.
      timeZone: UTC
```

pom file plugins

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```